# Billing-in-app error

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to test in-app-billing. But when I purchase a good digital, I am getting error message that "A server error has occurred.  Retry, or cancel and return to previous screen".

Can you suggest me to fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at the logcat output (from the Eclipse debug tab or 'adb logcat' from command line)

Comment: Elaborate the steps that you performed.. Have you got the in-app to show up its initialize screen? Also have you setup your market account(both in your app and in market) details?

Comment: Please give us more details. Have you uploaded it as a draft to the android market?

Comment: Yes. uploaded as draft. Then I got above message when try to purchase a digital good. I am in US. My carrier is AT&T. Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidKid Yes. I got initialize screen. Then when click "buy" button, I am getting above message.

Comment: @Ferdinand As suggested by JohnnyLambada, Google does restrict market features based on country and carrier,..etc. You might have any of those as a contradiction. Also it is recommended to update the Market app to the latest version for InApp to work correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Searching Google for this error message reveals a lot of users in non-US countries experiencing the same issue. Could it be that Google is blocking your phone from purchasing through a non-US carrier? Try someone else's app that also does in-app purchasing and see if you are able to purchase something using their app.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this topic, a lot of fixes can be found here
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=3f8673f746c68442&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this thread:

[Application Error : This version of the application is not configured for Market Billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522323/application-error-this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-market)

I have the same problems after upload new version of my application. After 1-3 hours problem was gone.
It's look like update problems on Google Play.