# Google play app "the version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play"

Tags: android, google-play

I updated app in app store and for the time it takes to process I get the message above when trying to subscribe with the test app of the same version. Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to update the app and keep the version of it?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522323/application-error-this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-market

Comment: Just noticed I never replied this. But yeah, it was the version of it. So the apk needs to always be signed and the version should be updated.