# TrivialDrive showing "This version of the application is not configured for billing through ......"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to run the TrivialDrive on a phone to test it. I have taken all the precautions i.e. Not running it on my own phone. I have checked the versions are the same. I have waited enough time for GP servers to update, etc....
Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

04-20 22:26:54.860: D/dalvikvm(3960): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 50% free 2727K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 22ms
04-20 22:26:54.885: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Loaded data: tank = 2
04-20 22:26:54.885: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Creating IAB helper.
04-20 22:26:54.885: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Starting setup.
04-20 22:26:54.885: D/IabHelper(3960): Starting in-app billing setup.
04-20 22:26:54.885: I/ApplicationPackageManager(3960): cscCountry is not German : XEU
04-20 22:26:54.910: D/IabHelper(3960): Billing service connected.
04-20 22:26:54.910: D/IabHelper(3960): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
04-20 22:26:54.915: D/IabHelper(3960): In-app billing version 3 supported for com.trivialdrivesample.free
04-20 22:26:54.925: D/IabHelper(3960): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
04-20 22:26:54.925: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Setup finished.
04-20 22:26:54.925: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Setup successful. Querying inventory.
04-20 22:26:54.925: D/IabHelper(3960): Starting async operation: refresh inventory
04-20 22:26:54.935: D/IabHelper(3960): Querying owned items, item type: inapp
04-20 22:26:54.935: D/IabHelper(3960): Package name: com.trivialdrivesample.free
04-20 22:26:54.935: D/IabHelper(3960): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
04-20 22:26:54.955: D/CLIPBOARD(3960): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Owned items response: 0
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Continuation token: null
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Querying SKU details.
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Querying owned items, item type: subs
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Package name: com.trivialdrivesample.free
04-20 22:26:54.965: D/IabHelper(3960): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/IabHelper(3960): Owned items response: 0
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/IabHelper(3960): Continuation token: null
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/IabHelper(3960): Querying SKU details.
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/IabHelper(3960): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/IabHelper(3960): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Query inventory finished.
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Query inventory was successful.
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/TrivialDrive(3960): User is NOT PREMIUM
04-20 22:26:54.975: D/TrivialDrive(3960): User DOES NOT HAVE infinite gas subscription.
04-20 22:26:55.000: D/dalvikvm(3960): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 29K, 49% free 2762K/5379K, external 467K/513K, paused 23ms
04-20 22:26:55.005: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.
04-20 22:27:03.490: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Buy gas button clicked.
04-20 22:27:03.495: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Launching purchase flow for gas.
04-20 22:27:03.495: D/IabHelper(3960): Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
04-20 22:27:03.495: D/IabHelper(3960): Constructing buy intent for gas, item type: inapp
04-20 22:27:03.550: D/IabHelper(3960): Launching buy intent for gas. Request code: 10001
04-20 22:27:03.620: D/CLIPBOARD(3960): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
04-20 22:27:16.580: D/TrivialDrive(3960): onActivityResult(10001,0,Intent { (has extras) }
04-20 22:27:16.580: D/IabHelper(3960): Ending async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
04-20 22:27:16.580: D/IabHelper(3960): Purchase canceled - Response: 5:Developer Error
04-20 22:27:16.580: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Purchase finished: IabResult: User canceled. (response: -1005:User cancelled), purchase: null
04-20 22:27:16.580: E/TrivialDrive(3960): **** TrivialDrive Error: Error purchasing: IabResult: User canceled. (response: -1005:User cancelled)
04-20 22:27:16.580: D/TrivialDrive(3960): Showing alert dialog: Error: Error purchasing: IabResult: User canceled. (response: -1005:User cancelled)
04-20 22:27:16.710: D/dalvikvm(3960): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 61K, 48% free 2840K/5379K, external 917K/920K, paused 21ms
04-20 22:27:16.715: D/TrivialDrive(3960): onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.

Comment: It would help you to receive assistance if you:

1. Formatted your logcat so that people could easily read it.

2. Described what you were expecting to see, and what you are actually seeing, and why this seems problematic to you.

3. Did some research and presented what you had learned, so that it's clear to us exactly what you cannot figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So I'll start again. When I try to run the simulation on a test device, after making sure the set up is as it should be, when I press on the 'Buy Gas' button, it goes to the Google Play screen showing the item I published in the app, but then it shows an alert box saying 'Application error' with message: This version of the application is not configured for billing etc....' I'm don't understand why its doing that. The resultCode is 0 obviously. Here is the logcat:

Comment: ...The resultCode is 0 obviously. I'm sorry I can't add the logcat, the windown is not giving me enough space to add it. Any ideas?(The GP app is version 3)

Comment: You can edit your original question to include a properly-formatted logcat, with carriage returns between the lines.  Check out the formatting tools available on the editor so that you can place the logcat in its own block of text.  You might also want to add your description of what happens, as not everyone will read the comment area.

Comment: Then, go to this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522323/application-error-this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-market

This page suggests that you're probably running your app directly from Eclipse using the debug key, rather than having generated an APK signed with your own, unique developer key.  You must have uploaded a signed APK to Google Play prior to testing, and you need to use the same APK (it can be revised, but the version code must match the one you uploaded, and it must be signed with the same key) on your own device when you are testing).

Comment: You also have to wait a while after uploading (typically 1-4 hours) before your app will start working.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments above, the problem now seems clear:

When you download the app to your device from Eclipse, Eclipse automatically signs your APK with your debug key (which is typically automatically generated by Eclipse), whereas the APK that you uploaded would have to be signed with your own (non-debug) signing key (because otherwise Google Play would not accept it). So, the signature of the file with which you are testing (from Eclipse) and that of the uploaded APK, do not match.  That is what is causing the error that indicates that your app is not configured for billing.

You do *not* have to receive the APK directly from Google Play for testing; you can just load the same signed APK as you uploaded to Google Play from your PC, via a USB cable. In fact, so long as your local APK has the same signature and the same VersionCode as the APK that you uploaded, you can send it to your device over USB using ADB and it should run. This is important because when you are testing you will want to make various minor fixes without having to re-upload and wait several hours each time before testing.

Comment: Thank you I understand this. But the situation I have is that I am signing the apk with a saved key that I use to upload my apps to GP. So in theory, yes, the uploaded apk and and the app that I upload to my phone via usb should be the same and signed with the same apk. But this is not the case. I get this error telling me that the app on my phone has a different signature to the app i'm trying to download.

Comment: Hi. I actually managed to get it to work! So now I move onto the next problem - how do I debug the app running on the phone? How do I run my signed APK file through eclipse in order to debug it? Thanks.

Comment: The easiest approach is to keep using the static IDs (e.g., android.test.purchased) to get your code debugged.  These should work fine even with the DEBUG key that is generated by Eclipse.  Then, for final testing, switch back to your actual SKUs and  generate a signed APK as you have just done, and then use Log statements to work out any final bugs.

Although that works for me, it is also possible to replace Eclipse's debug key with your own key and then test from Eclipse using that.  I don't do that because I'm concerned about the security of my signing key, but I believe it is possible.

Comment: The Eclipse debug key is typically in a file called debug.keystore.  This is usually in your SDK main folder's sub-folder called .android.

BTW, most people will not answer a question that shows insufficient independent research effort (and I am right now in the process of promising myself that I will not do it again).  If you make a better effort to research and present your questions in the future, you'll probably obtain more than one response.

Comment: Thank you. I take your points on board. I did actually do research about debugging and have come up with an interesting link I'd like to share.http://www.mobileoped.com/2012/04/13/android-google-play-in-app-billing-debug-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Carl for you points. I read over and over again and seemed to do everything right, except I was uploading the APK direct from Eclipse to the phone via a cable. The documentation is not clear enough. It should say that the app must only be downloaded from GP, and not from any development environment. The minute I did that, it worked. Thanks again. I'm off to working on my real app now for IAB. ;-)